# Import Accumulo Libraries in Scala SBT project

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, accumulo

I want to know about, using Accumulo or any other java libraries in SBT projects.

I used Intellij to automatically import libraries, and it imported but getting errors in Intellij and at runtime/project build like:-
`Cannot resolve _`. In `import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.__`

I used these steps to include:-
`File > Project Structure > Libraries(In left Pan) > Clicked`+`icon located at top left in middle pan > Selected from Maven >` Searched `Accumulo and Selected org.apache.accumulo.core.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look for Maven dependencies in Maven central it also gives you the syntax for adding the dependencies in several build tools - Including SBT 
for instance if you look up  [Apache Accumulo core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.accumulo/accumulo-core/1.8.1)
you'd see the SBT usage as : `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.accumulo" % "accumulo-core" % "1.8.1"`

[image]

Comment: The interface at Maven Central's own indexer/search site shows the same: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.accumulo%7Caccumulo-core%7C1.8.1%7Cjar

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz for directing me in right direction. A few more I points I want to add are following:-

1. You can add your **JAR** files in **lib** directory of your project **root** directory.
2. The step with which I was having problem is also working now with minor changes with major effects.

   The correct steps for IntelliJ are:-

   - > File -> Project Structure -> Libraries  -> Click + icon in top left of second column
   - > Chose Maven( or other if you are having jar files)
   - > Search Your Library
   - > Click on Download to {Project Root Directory}/lib
   - > Press Enter or Click `OK`
   - > It will take some time proportional to size of lib and number of it's dependencies. After downloading a popup will come
   - > Press shift and click the modules in which you want to import the library.